# Do not open category in new page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

in my store I have an html banner that opens the category pages in new tabs, how can I avoid new tabs? I need the category to open on the same page. Next I show you my html code:

```
[container overflow="visible"][one_third margin="25px 0 0" content_width="96%"][tm_banner backgroung_img="https://my-domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/NOTEBOOK-verde.png" link_url="https://my-domain.com/product-category/notebook/"][/tm_banner][/one_third][one_third margin="25px 10px 0" content_width="96%"][tm_banner backgroung_img="https://my-domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/banner-celular-verde.png" link_url="https://my-domain.com/product-category/celulares/"][/tm_banner][/one_third][one_third margin="25px 0 0 20px" content_width="96%" classname="home_banner_3"][tm_banner backgroung_img="https://my-domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/gammers-verde.png" target="" link_url="https://my-domain.com.com/product-category/gamers/" ][/tm_banner][/one_third][/container]
```

I am using the theme: Branchy Version: 1.0

The code results in a banner like the one in this image:

[image: Banner HTML]

thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have documentation for the `tm_banner` shortcode? Otherwise search the source code for its declaration and look for an option like `target`.

Comment: hello @JosefWittmann in the documentation there is nothing about it, I have already tried with target="self" target="_self", but it does not work.

Comment: Can you link the source code?

Comment: I meant the PHP source code for the `tm_banner` shortcode...

Comment: I did tests inside the shortcode using: href="URL" target="self" but it does not work.

Comment: @Josef Wittmann I not only have the shortcode

Answer (score 0):

I've looked up the `tm_banner` shortcode and it seems `target=_blank` is hard-coded in there.

You have a few options now:

1. Write your own shortcode copying the shortcodes implementation.
2. Update the implementation. But be aware that updates may overwrite your edits.
3. Use JavaScript to update the target: `[...document.querySelectorAll(".tm_banner_inner a")].forEach(linkEl => linkEl.removeAttribute("target"))`. Be aware to call this script only when the elements are loaded.

Comment: Excuse me, my programming knowledge is basic, can you help me with the complete code? Thank you.

Comment: can you help me please?

Comment: Have a look at how to use JavaScript in WordPress in general. A quick online search will help you there.

Comment: ´[...document.querySelectorAll(".tm_banner_inner a")].forEach(linkEl => linkEl.removeAttribute("target"))´ I add that code in a file .js and I call him from the fuctions.php ?

Comment: You add that to a .js file and **enqueue** it from your functions.php